# The selector "app-subscription" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have to create a modal for one of my website. I have implemented ngx-bootstrap modal for that. 
I have defined the component in my bootstrap. It is running perfectly but when I'm viewing the console it is showing error message as

> The selector "app-subscription" did not match any elements

Below is the code snippet for subscription.component.ts

```
export class SubscriptionComponent implements OnInit {
  closeBtnName: string;
  public email_id;
  subscribed:Boolean= false;
  showsubscribe: Boolean = true;
  public emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX)]);

  constructor( public bsModalRef: BsModalRef, private 
  submit_service: 
    SubmitService, private modalService: BsModalService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
  }
```

}

and for the home.component.ts

```
if(this.router.url.includes('subscribe')){

  this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(SubscriptionComponent)
  this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName  = 'Close'
}
```

As per the ngx-bootstrap documentation I have added that in my entryComponents. 
Code snippet for app.module.ts

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent, SubscriptionComponent]
```

Please suggest me a fix for that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added the `SubscriptionComponent` in the `entryComponents` array of the module.

Comment: Thanks! I have removed it from bootstrap and added it in entryComponents. It is working fine now. :-)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.